# SQL inner join is not combining tables in VIEW

Tags: sql, view

I can't seem to join my `user` table with this ROI calculated VIEW.

```
SELECT 
    `c`.`user` AS `user`,
    COALESCE(((SUM(`c`.`amountbet`) * 100.0) / NULLIF(SUM(`c`.`amountwon`), 0)),
            0) AS `roi`
FROM
    `clubusers` AS `c`
INNER JOIN `users` AS `u` ON `c`.`user` = `u`.`id`
GROUP BY `c`.`user`
```

That's what I've tried but it only returns...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `users` table is superfluous in this query.  Can't you just use this?

```
SELECT c.user, 
       COALESCE(SUM(c.amountbet) * 100.0 / NULLIF(SUM(c.amountwon), 0), 0) AS roi
FROM clubusers c
GROUP BY c.user;
```

Comment: I would like to return the user data with each row, like their email, startdate etc.

Comment: If you want additional data to appear in the results, then you need to include those columns in the SELECT statement - eg. SELECT c.user, u.email, u.startdate, etc. ....  Just adding a JOIN to another table will not automatically make the columns from that table appear (unless your select statement is just SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ...)

Comment: Yep that got it. Thanks again!